# Calculating minimum pairwise distance

Tags: algorithm

I have two list of 2d vectors of size `m` and `n` and I need to find minimum distance between each node of first list with the nodes of 2d list. I wonder if it is possible to do it in better time than `O(nm)`. Let's assume that we can change data structures as we please. What do you think?

Comment: `2d vectors` - do you mean 2d points?

Comment: @MBo yes. something line `{x, y}`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree

Comment: Look at `bichromatic closest pair problem`